# Generating white noise with a particular colour set using Imagemagick

Tags: random, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to generate white noise, to use as frames for a key frame animation sequence.

Found this tutorial that explains how to make random noise using ImageMagick
http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2009/09/making-noise-with-imagemagick.html

which obvious works.

What I want is to generate noise using the following colours

- White
- Black
- Grey
- Brown
- Pink

Is there a way to ask Imagemagick to use these specific colours?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes- add noise takes a channel, set that to iMagick::Channel_Blue, etc. or with imagemagick commandline, use the -channel flag.